# Prestashop 1.7 Module Admin action view don't work

Tags: module, namespaces, prestashop, admin, prestashop-1.7

I created an admin module to manage the data of a new table. The list is displayed in the back office. I want to create a detail view for each line, but the "view" action does not work! I have this error that appears:

> ClassNotFoundException in AdminController.php line 1632: Attempted to
>   load class "Guides" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use"
>   statement?

```
    require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mymodguides/classes/Guides.php';

class AdminMyModGuidesController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    protected $_pagination = array(20, 50, 100, 300, 1000);
    protected $_default_pagination = 20;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->table = 'guides';
        $this->identifier = 'id_guide';
        $this->className = 'Guides';
        $this->module = 'mymodguides';
        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_guide' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'align' => 'center','width' => 30),
            'name' => array('title' => $this->l('Name'), 'align' => 'center','width' => 150),
            'professional' => array('title' => $this->l('Prof'), 'align' => 'center','width' => 30),
            'ranking' => array('title' => $this->l('Ranking'), 'align' => 'center','width' => 30),
            'active' => array('title' => $this->l('Active'), 'align' => 'center','width' => 30),
            'date_add' => array('title' => $this->l('Date'), 'align' => 'center','width' => 30)
        );

        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_select = "CONCAT(c.`firstname` ,' ', c.`lastname` ) as name";
        $this->_join = 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`fk_id_customer`)';

        // Add actions
        $this->addRowAction('view');
    }

    public function renderView(){
        $tpl = $this->context->smarty->createTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mymodguides/views/templates/admin/view.tpl');
        return $tpl->fetch();
    }

    protected function l($string, $class = null, $addslashes = false, $htmlentities = true)
    {
        if ( _PS_VERSION_ >= '1.7') {
            return Context::getContext()->getTranslator()->trans($string);
        } else {
            return parent::l($string, $class, $addslashes, $htmlentities);
        }
    }

}
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Looks like your class Guides is in a custom namespace. Classes that extend ObjectModel should be in global namespace. Or you could try writing full class name with its namespace in `$this->className`, I never tried that but I doubt it would work.

Comment: Thank you. It was a stupid error, the name of my class was badly written ... (missing a s)